# Configure Spring boot with H2 database and Liquibase

Tags: spring-boot, junit, h2, liquibase

I am using Spring boot2, I am trying to configure a Unit Test using H2 + Liquibase + JUNIT.

I think that liquibase is not executing the changeLog files and apply the SQL Commands, the unit test does not recognized my tables.

I put wrongs sql in my file to see if the changelog files are executed, but, seems that is not being executing.

Why my application can not access table? Maybe liquibase is not executing?

in my *src/test/resource* I have this file: *application.yml*

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-api
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:myDB;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    username: sa
    password: sags
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    user: sa
    password: sags
    change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        use_sql_comments: true
        format_sql: true
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /console
```

My Test class:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FooRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepository;

    @Test
    public void findAllMustReturnAnything() {
        List<Object> result = fooRepository.tables();
    }
}
```

The FooRepository method:

```
@Query(value = "SHOW TABLES", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object> tables();
```

When I run my Unit Test I have the follow result:

[image]

My changelog file is in : *src/main/resources/db*

UPDATE: I found why liquibase was not executing my sql codes. It was because my SQL files had "dbms:mysql", so, how I am executing with H2 liquibase will not apply.

```
-- changeset 1.0:2 dbms:mysql
command
-- rollback command
```

Now, I need to know why my selected database in the session is not myDB.

Comment: If your changelog file is in src/main/resources, then its location is not `classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml`. It is `classpath:db.changelog-master.xml` (assuming that's the correct file name)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put "db" in my explanation, my file is in: src/main/resources/db
When I change the filename to test if will failure, it fails, so the file is found during the executing, but does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I think in you case Spring turns on auto configure datasource.(https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.html)

Try to turn it off.

```
spring.test.database.replace=none
```

And there is some unnecessary configuration.

```
  liquibase:
    user: sa
    password: sags
```

You can remove user&password, liquibase use it from datasource.